# Are there non-Chess games that use a chess board with "black on the right"

Tags: chessboards

Are there any non-Chess games that use a chess board where the bottom-right hand cell for each player is black rather than white?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spain checkers is played with the board placed that way. Alternatively you can place the board the same way as chess, but then pieces are placed at light squares.

Comment: Interesting re Spanish Checkers - I'll look into that!